# Unable to import a file in python

Tags: python

I want to import a file in a local directory but python refused to do so and it gives error everytime i do so.

I tried putting "from Admin_login import Admin_login" but it gives an error saying

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Admin_login'"

my code:-(main.py)

```
from .Admin_login import Admin_login

loggsin = Admin_login.login()

if loggsin == True:
    print("You are logged in")
```

This is the Admin_login.py file

```
import json
import os

def load_data():
    with open("data.json", "r") as f:
        Data = json.load(f)
    return Data

class Admin_login():
        def login(self):
            Login = False
            while Login == False:
                id = input("Enter the id you want to login = ")
                data = load_data()
                if id == data["id"]:
                    print(data["name"])
                    passord = input("Enter the password = ")
                    if passord == data["password"]:
                        print("You are successfully logged in")
                        Login = True
                        return Login
                        os.system('cls')

                else:
                    print("The id doesn't exist... Please try again!")
                    Login = False
                    return Login
                    os.system('cls')



if __name__ == '__main__' :
    Admin_login()
```

and the error it gives is :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\LibApp\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Admin_login import Admin_login
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

pls help

Comment: If the two files are in the same directory, remove the `.` and it should work

Comment: do what Lecdi says above, but then you will probably get an error in `main.py` because that function doesn't exist. You will need to call `Admin_login.Admin_login()` in your first line of non-import code.

Comment: Can you provide the directory/file structure of your code?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the '.' is giving you the trouble. When you add a dot to a directory name, it is referring to a relative directory and not an absolute one. That's what that error you're getting is referring to. If those two files are in the same directory, you can just remove the dot and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it ain't working for me